# S3 Lifecycle rule for changing storage type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have following directory structure in S3 ( assets is the bucketname ).
I have configured a lifecycle rule with a prefix of

```
asmt/DEV/exam/
```

to change the storage type from standard to standard-IA after 30 days for all files.

But when I check the storage type of jpg files after 30 days they remain standard .
Can some one guide me.

```
assets
   asmt/
       DEV/
           exam/
                152752/
                      profile/1.jpg,2,jpg etc
                152753/
                      profile/1.jpg,2,jpg etc
                152754/
                      profile/1.jpg,2,jpg etc
```

Comment: Do you have versioning enabled on your bucket? Or any other lifecycle rules in place for the same bucket? And could you post your actual lifecycle rule as a json - ```aws s3api get-bucket-lifecycle --bucket my-bucket
```

Comment: how big are your files? [S3 does not transition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/lifecycle-transition-general-considerations.html) objects that are smaller than 128 KB

Comment: what rule you are using?

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of your setup, or code if CloudFormation or SDK/CLI? Also do you have examples of your images?

Comment: Turns out the files are less than 128k in size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For moving the objects from S3-Standard to S3-Standard-IA there are majorly two conditions that need to be satisfied:

1. The object needs to be stored in Standard Storage for a minimum of 30 days
2. The objects need to be more than 128KB in size

If your objects satisfy both these conditions then the object must be moved. If it still doesn't then it may be some other issue and maybe you must raise a support ticket and let them look into it